# Regex implementation for escape sequence

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I have an application which takes any string and types the value in a notepad.Now if anything gets enclosed by angular brackets e.g-`<domain>` it becomes a variable for the application and during execution it asks for the value for it to store and types the same value in the notepad.Now my pain is I want to type `<domain>` as a text without asking for the value for it.What can be the regex implementation to skip treating  the `<>` brackets as variable and type as it is.

Comment: What regex did you use to accept <X> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a regex the <> characters do not require escaping.

The following code proves this.

```
String pattern = ".+<domain>.+";
String content = "this is the <domain> word";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
boolean b = m.matches();
```

The result is b==true which means the pattern was found in the content.

Comment: This pattern will actually accept all text containing <domain> with extra padding of at least 1 from both sides...